# How do I tell mstest to ignore tests in a base class but not in subclasses?

Tags: c#, inheritance, mstest

I have a log parser that I am working on, and this log parser has an `ILogStore` interface that defines the base methods for any log record storage engine (in memory, in a database, etc..).  The idea is that developers and users can add or remove log storage engines via the MEF plugin interface.

However, in order to confirm that a `ILogStore` implementation can correctly store, filter, and retrieve log entries I created a base class for unit/integration/API testing:

```
public class LogStoreBaseTests
{
    protected ILogStore _store;

    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Store_And_Retrieve_Records() { }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Filter_Records_By_Inclusive_Text() { }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Filter_Records_By_Exclusive_Text() { }

    // etc...
}
```

I test my implemented tasks by doing something like:

```
[TestClass]
public class InMemoryLogStoreTests : LogStoreBaseTests
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _store = new InMemoryLogStore();
    }
}
```

This works good except that MsTest notices that the methods in the base class have `[TestMethod]` but errors because the class doesn't have `[TestClass]`, which it doesn't because it's not valid tests on it's own.

How can I tell MsTest to ignore the methods when not run from a subclass?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out MSTest has an `[Ignore]` Attribute.  I placed that and the `[TestClass]` attribute on my base test, and it correctly ignores the test methods for the base tests while using the base test methods when run under a subclass

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can tell MS test to ignore certain tests, but you can ask it to not run certain test categories.

for example following attribute puts the test in integration category

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class IntegrationTestAttribute : TestCategoryBaseAttribute
    {
        public IList<string> categories;

        public IntegrationTestAttribute()
        {
            this.categories = new List<String> { "Integration" };
        }

        public override IList<string> TestCategories
        {
            get
            {
                return this.categories;
            }
        }
    }
```

Another approach you could take it to mark your base class as abstract and make your tests call certain abstract methods, that way anyone who is implementing your class will implement those methods.

for example

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseUnitTest
{
    public BaseUnitTest(){}
    private TestContext testContextInstance;        
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }        
    [TestMethod]
    public void can_run_this_test_for_each_derived_class()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(this.ReturnMeSomething());
    }
    protected abstract string ReturnMeSomething();
}

[TestClass]
public class Derived1 : BaseUnitTest
{

    protected override string ReturnMeSomething()
    {
        return "test1";
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Derived2 : BaseUnitTest
{
    protected override string ReturnMeSomething()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

yet another approach would be to use AOP like MSTestExtension does , code can be found [here](http://mstestextensions.codeplex.com/)

Comment: wow, duh.  Not sure why I didn't think to just mark the base class as abstract.  That might actually do it, just need to test it when I get home.

Comment: Just setting the test to abstract didn't work.  How do you tell MSTest to not run specific categories?

Comment: in visual studio test list editor, you can group tests by categories, i will put the answer with abstract/derived class tomorrow.

Comment: I realized that MSTest has an `[Ignore]` attribute, and that is much easier than these methods unfortunately.    Both of those make it hard to immediately see what's going on in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Never saw such approach when one tests fixture inheriting an other one... I would suggest considering an other approach rather than working around such tests infrastructure.

Consider either:

1. Move all tests in a single class marked by `[TestClass]` OR
2. Create two completely separate test classed so they will not be coupled and affect each other

Comment: I *want* them to affect each other, to make sure that the core functionality of all `ILogStore` implementations are consistent in their behavior, and when the requirements change for what an `ILogStore` retrieval method is meant to return it's confirmed as working for the new requirements for all implementations.